# Difference between ":" and "=" in HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am very new to HTML and CSS but while learning I ran into something that I was curious about.
How come when you want to style or change font size etc. you use `:`.

Example: `style="color: red; font-size: 50px"`.

But when you want to link to let's say your stylesheet you use `=`.

Example: `link type="text/css"; rel="stylesheet"; href="stylesheet.css"`.

What's the difference? Because basically when you say `color: red`, your saying you want the color to `= red`, so why not just use that? This is just a curiosity thing nothing serious but your answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `:`, it's CSS. When you use `=`, it's HTML. It's just two languages with each one has its own different method for assigning attributes (HTML) and properties (CSS).

Comment: Quick response, Thank you. Also thank you for editing my post I don't know how to make it look like that but I'll figure it out and make sure future post are easier to read.

Comment: No problem and welcome to Pro Webmasters.

Comment: Neither HTML nor CSS has variables; they are not programming languages. HTML has attributes, CSS has properties. But it is indeed a matter of simple syntactic difference between the two languages.

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela: You're right, I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Each programming language has its syntax.

For HTML, styles' properties are defined by

```
property_name: property_value
```

And also for HTML, markup properties are defined by

```
markup_name = markup_value
```

Answer (score 1):

Every Language has its own syntax and structure and in html assignment is done using "=" and in css assignment is done using ":" .

Example:

In css

```
  body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

In Html

```
bgcolor="red"
```

but in css you can use : for selecting specific element from html

Example:

```
input:checked {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

This css is applied when input is checked